# What is the difference between "mov (%rax),%eax" and "mov %rax,%eax"?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, cpu-registers

What is the difference between `mov (%rax),%eax` and `mov %rax,%eax`? I'm sure this is a simple question, but I can't find the answer anywhere.

Here is the original code that prompted my question:

```
mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
mov    (%rax),%eax
lea    (%rax,%rax,1),%edx
mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
mov    %edx,(%rax)
mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
mov    (%rax),%eax
```

Comment: `mov (%rax),%eax` fetches from memory, and `mov %rax,%eax` is invalid due to operand size mismatch, but if it were valid it would simply transfer from one register to another.

Answer (score 14):

In AT&T syntax, the instruction:

> ```
> mov (%rax), %eax                  # AT&T syntax
> ```

or, equivalently in Intel syntax:

> ```
> mov eax, DWORD PTR [rax]          ; Intel syntax
> ```

*dereferences* the memory address stored in `rax`, reads a 32-bit value from that memory address, and stores it in the `eax` register.

Because the memory address being dereferenced is stored in `rax`, it can be a 64-bit address, which is necessary when running on a 64-bit operating system.

However, the data *pointed to* by that memory address is only 32 bits in size, so it can be stored in the 32-bit `eax` register.

Note that this instruction will implicitly zero the upper 32 bits of the `rax` register, so that the lower 32-bit half (called `eax`) will contain the loaded data, and the upper 32-bit half will be empty.

The parentheses in AT&T syntax (or the square brackets in Intel syntax) are your clue that this instruction treats the contents of the register as if they were a pointer.
This is what makes it different from, for example:

> ```
> mov %rcx, %rax                    # AT&T syntax
> ```

> ```
> mov rax, rcx                      ; Intel syntax
> ```

This simply copies the contents of the `rcx` register into the `rax` register. There is no dereferencing being done. The values in the register(s) are acted on directly.

Note that the above example was *similar* to the other example from your question:

> ```
> mov %rax, %eax                    # AT&T syntax (INVALID!)
> ```

> ```
> mov eax, rax                      ; Intel syntax (INVALID!)
> ```

but not identical. This last case is actually an *invalid instruction* because there is an operand-size mismatch. If it were valid, the instruction would be copying the contents of the 64-bit `rax` register into the 32-bit `eax` register. Of course, this is impossible. Narrowing conversions are not allowed, so it will not assemble.

If you *really* wanted to do this, you would have to decide which half of the 64-bit value in `rax` that you wanted to throw away. If you decided to throw away the upper bits and copy only the lower bits to `eax`, you wouldn't need to do anything—just use `eax` directly. If, however, you wanted to throw away the lower bits and use only the upper bits, you would first do a right-shift by 32.

---

<sub>Note that this is a fairly simple, general-reference question. You could have looked up the answer in any book on x86 assembly language, and a tutorial should have taught you about the significance of the parentheses/brackets syntax. Please see the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for some tutorials and other general-reference information.</sub>