# Difference between "%register" and "(%register)" in x86 assembly AT&T syntax?

Tags: assembly, x86, att

So far my current understanding is something along the lines of:
`movq %rdi, %rax` will move the value from the register `%rdi` to the register `%rax`

and `movq (%rdi), %rax` will move the value from memory at `(%rdi)` to the register `%rax`

However, I'm having trouble understanding what this actually means functionally. In what instance will these two assembly lines end with a different result?

Comment: It's so bizarre. You know everything but seek for some functional meaning.

Comment: there's no "C assembly language"

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc thank you for the correction, what way should I call it?

Comment: In the AT&T syntax, the parentheses indicates that the register is to be used to reference a memory location, rather than the register itself. The same difference when referencing/dereferencing a pointer variable in C. `moveq (%rdi), %rax` is to assembly where `a = *d` is to C. `moveq %rdi, (%rax)` is to assembly where `*a = d` is to C.

Comment: near duplicate: [What is the difference between "mov (%rax),%eax" and "mov %rax,%eax"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41232333)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will yield a different result every time the memory at adress (%rdi) does not contain its own adress. In other words, almost always. And when not, it's just a coincidence or a consequence of very unusual code.

Some C to demonstrate the equivalent question "When will the two printf statements print the same result?"

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int a,*p;
  int b=5;
  p=&b;

  a=*p;
  printf("%d\n", a);
  a=(int)p;
  printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

And, yes, this yields the warning `cast from pointer to integer of different size` but that's beside the point.

Comment: This had me confused for a bit but it made me realize that i'm pretty sure I had the concept backwards until now. (%rdi) is basically the pointer to %rdi, correct?

Comment: (%rdi) is a pointer, but not to %rdi. It is a pointer to the address %rdi.

Comment: In my example, the equivalent question would be if `*p` is a pointer to `p`. It is not. It is a pointer to the address contained in `p`.

Comment: I would say that `(%rdi)` is either the *dereferenced pointer* or the *pointed-to value* (i.e.: `*p`), whereas `%rdi` is the *address* stored by the pointer (i.e.: `p`).