# Can't understand value in %rax in simple Assembly x86

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct item {
    int low; int high; char label[16];
} Item;

typedef struct item_coll {
    size_t length; Item *items[];
} ItemColl;

extern char *find_first_in_range(ItemColl *ic, int rlow, int rhigh);

/*
char *find_first_in_range(ItemColl *ic, int rlow, int rhigh) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ic->length; i++)
        if (ic->items[i]->low >= rlow && ic->items[i]->high <= rhigh)
            return &ic->items[i]->label[0];
    return NULL;
}
* */

int main() {

    struct item fruits[] = {
        {10, 20, "Apple"},
        {12, 14, "Pear"},
        { 8, 12, "Banana"},
        { 2,  4, "Grape"},
        {15, 35, "Watermelon"}
    };


    struct item_coll *basket = malloc (sizeof *basket + 5 * sizeof *basket->items);
    basket->length = 5;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)  
        basket->items[i] = &fruits[i];

    char *label = find_first_in_range (basket, 12, 15);
    printf ("%s\n", label);

    free (basket);

    return 0;
}
```

I have this C program and the goal is to make the `find_first_in_range` function in assembly. Right now I'm just trying to get to the `10` in `Apple` but it's giving me a weird value in `%rax`.

This is what I've done in assembly:

```
    .globl find_first_in_range

# *ic   is passed in %rdi
# rlow  is passed in %rsi
# rhigh is passed in %rdx

find_first_in_range:
    mov %rdi, %rax
```

[image]

`%rsi` holds `12` and `%rdx` holds `15` which are the left and right limits I passed in `find_first_in_range (basket, 12, 15);`, but shouldn't `%rax` hold `10`? From the first element of `fruits[]`.

Another question I have is how do I access, for example, the length of `basket`? Which is `5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s `ic` itself that’s in `%rdi`: the *pointer* to the `ItemColl`.  So `ic->length`, being the first element in that structure, is (after the `mov`) just `(%rax)` (presumably 8 bytes long).

Comment: I don't understand what you said. Is `%rax` holding the `ic->length`?

Comment: @Vegas: RAX holds the *pointer*, as I said.  You use parentheses (in AT&T syntax) to fetch the value stored at that location (or nearby).

Comment: Doing `mov (%rax), %rax` after `mov %rdi, %rax` worked flawlessly, but I don't understand how the parenthesis fetched the value and why it wouldn't work without parenthesis.

Comment: Also I just realised that I could simply do `mov (%rdi), %rax`

Comment: I'm reading the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46679574/difference-between-register-and-register-in-x86-assembly-att-syntax

He states that (%rdi) will fetch the value from memory at %rdi, is that correct?

Comment: @Vegas: Yes, that’s what it does—as I believe I said.  As for *why*, it’s just the syntax that selects the appropriate addressing mode for the instruction (rather than merely using a register).

Comment: I don't know if you're still reading this but if you are what could I do to access the `10` in `fruits`? I'm trying to add different offsets to `%rdi` but it's not working.

Comment: (The site of course notifies an author of comments on their posts.)  That 10 is behind another pointer: you want `(8(%rdi))`, but you can’t do that in one instruction (so you have to insert a `mov`).

Answer (score 1):

> `%rsi` holds `12` and `%rdx` holds `15` which are the left and right limits I passed in 
>   `find_first_in_range (basket, 12, 15);`, but shouldn't `%rax` hold `10`? From the first element of `fruits[]`.

Why would it?! You passed in a *pointer* to `struct item_coll`. What you have is a *pointer* to `struct item_coll`. Then you need to do indirect accesses through this pointer to get `length` and *`LEA`* the address of `basket->items`, and use indirection through this to access the values within the structures pointed to by the pointers.

The best way to understand how to do an operation in assembly to make a **simple C function** that does the same operation and then compile the function with **high enough** optimization level (O2!) and then to understand the generated code.